# How do I get my balance table to show standard errors instead of standard deviation in stata?

Tags: stata

I am trying to replicate a table from an article for a class and all my numbers are correct except the standard errors. It is automatically showing standard deviation.

```
global myvars MSBS male age officer Army Navy AirForce
global mysplitvar FY1991

eststo group1_means: estpost summarize $myvars if $mysplitvar == 0
eststo group2_means: estpost summarize $myvars if $mysplitvar == 1

esttab group1_means group2_means using Table1_REPEX1.html, se(3) replace ///
cell(   mean(fmt(3)) ///
    sd(fmt(3) par)) ///
mtitle("Choice Cohort (FY1991)" "Choice Cohort (FY1992)") label collabels(none)
```

[The numbers in parenthesis are wrong - this shows sd and I need se](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4QhB.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this using `ci` instead of `summarize`. Here's a working example. Note that the name of the estimate changes from `mean` to `b`:

```
sysuse auto, clear 
 
global myvars     price mpg weight 
global mysplitvar foreign 

eststo group1_means: estpost ci $myvars if $mysplitvar == 0
eststo group2_means: estpost ci $myvars if $mysplitvar == 1

esttab group1_means group2_means, replace ///
cell( b(fmt(3)) ///
      se(fmt(3) par)) ///
mtitle("Domestic cars" "Foreign cars") label collabels(none)
```

Here's a quick math check showing that the standard error is indeed what's shown.

```
display "Check calcultion if standard error by hand for domestic price: "
sum price if $mysplitvar == 0
display r(sd)/sqrt(r(N))
display "Matches top left cell!"
```

Screenshot of the output below:
[image]